# onResume() not being called on resuming app, screen becomes black

Tags: java, android, onresume, homescreen

So I fixed some other bugs I had with my app and a new annoying bug arose. I can run my game fine and everything works well. The problem is when I exit the app and then go into recent apps from my home and then I click on my game, the screen turns black (Game loop is still running though). I put a line of code in the onCreate(),onPause() and onResume() methods to tell me when they are called. This is the order they get called when I start the app:

`onCreate() then -->
onResume()`
I then exit my app:
`onPause()`

But when I return, onResume() does not appear in logcat and neither does onCreate() if you were wondering. Thank you!

Also, there are no errors that show up in LogCat.

EDIT, heres my code (p.s. Anaglyph is the name of my game and the name of the gameview class):

GameView(Anaglyph.class):
[Paste Bin Entry 1](http://pastebin.com/XfqPUf6X)

GameThread(MainThread.class):
[Paste Bin Entry 2](http://pastebin.com/90bYCufX)

MainActivity(MainActivity.class): 
[Paste Bin Entry 3](http://pastebin.com/tMeVWsBj)

Comment: I do not have a ton of experience with the SurfaceHolder but I would recommend checking your surfaceholder callbacks to see if you are appropriately managing the surface considering the activities lifecycle changes. It sounds like something is getting stuck in a loop which blocks the activity callbacks.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Im completely new to android so I probobly know even less than you about that :P

Comment: I am guessing (have not verified) that when your app is paused the the surface is destroy and probably needs to be created again when your app resumes. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html Specifically the class overview.

Comment: In my first comment I meant to say SurfaceView not SurfaceHolder...

Comment: Its ok. I decided to remake the whole main setup of my game from viewing another tutorial and it works perfectly. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's code looks like mine and you have the same problem, just restructire your program using this example:http://androidhelpkatariya.blogspot.ca/2012/11/surface-view-example.html
     Hope it helps, worked great for me!